# react native onPress fires container element's onPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

```
<MaterialIcons
                    name={'call'}
                    size={20}
                    onPress={()=>{this.props.toggleSomething(true);}}
/>
```

This material icon is inside a react-native-elements ListItem which has it's own onPress.

On pressing the icon the ListItem's onPress is also fired.

How can we prevent this?

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: Please provide full code of your ListItem and MaterialIcon with styles

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create your own ListItem component to have total control over it